# How to approach multiple Rest queries in same method

Tags: query, httprequest, filters

I have written a Rest Get method where I get a response based on id like, /services/apexrest/invoices/a000X000015ABc2

How do I go about if I want to use this same method for following calls:

```
- GET <BASE_URL>/invoices/?customerId=<someId>&month=1
- GET <BASE_URL>/invoices/?customerId=<someId>&filter=shop&month=3
- GET <BASE_URL>/invoices/?customerId=<someId>&addressId=8212BJ154
```

Do I need to write if statements like if month!= null, if filter!= null and use this in WHERE Id = :invoiceId or month__c = month or is there a general pattern for this

Get method:

```
@HttpGet
    global static void getinvoiceById() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        // grab the invoiceId from the end of the URL
        String invoiceId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        List<Invoice__c> result =  [SELECT customerId__c , addressId__c , invoiceId__c , invoiceType__c , invoiceTypeLocalized__c  , invoiceDate__c  ,
                                    paymentDueDate__c , invoiceNumber__c  , startDate__c , endDate__c , periodDescription__c , amount__c , 
                                    vatAmount__c , totalAmount__c 
                                    FROM invoice__c
                                    WHERE Id = :invoiceId];

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may build a dynamic query using if --- else if --- else, depending on the parameters in your URI.

The structure will be something like this:

```
@HttpGet
global static void getinvoiceById() {
    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    Map<String, String> reqParamsMap = request.params;

    String strQuery = 'SELECT customerId__c , addressId__c , invoiceId__c , invoiceType__c , invoiceTypeLocalized__c  , invoiceDate__c  ,
                                paymentDueDate__c , invoiceNumber__c  , startDate__c , endDate__c , periodDescription__c , amount__c , 
                                vatAmount__c , totalAmount__c 
                                FROM invoice__c WHERE ';

    try {
        if(reqParamsMap.containsKey('customerId')){              
            String invId = reqParamsMap.get('customerId');
            strQuery += ' Id =\''+invId+'\'';

        }
        else if (reqParamsMap.containsKey('month')){
            String month = reqParamsMap.get('month');
            strQuery += ' month = .......';
        }
        else if (other condition) {
            //append condition to query
        }

        //be careful with WHERE / AND / OR conditions
        //debug your query to see if it's well built before executing it
        System.debug('## query : ' + strQuery); 
        List<Invoice__c> result = database.Query(strQuery);

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //catch errors
    }

}
```

You may amend the code accordingly.

Comment: I get an error on String invId = reqParamsMap.containsKey('customerId');  should this be keyvalue?

Comment: Debug `reqParamsMap ` and see what you it contains.

Comment: I cant save the class because of this error : Illegal assignment from Boolean to String on the mentioned line

Comment: Be sure to add code to defend against [SOQL Injection](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_prevent_soql_injection).

Comment: @Thomas, Map<String, Object> maybe, depending on what you are passing in request.

Comment: @N.B. Figured out this can be done more simple by: String customerId = RestContext.request.params.get('customerId');
        String month = RestContext.request.params.get('month');

Comment: @N.B.  String month = reqParamsMap.containsKey('month');  should be  String month = reqParamsMap.get('month');  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Thomas, yeah sorry. That was a typo, was in a lil rush. I copied/pasted from the line above. Corrected the answer not to mislead. Thanks.